# Toggle button toggles on the second click

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling into creating a toggle button. I want a script that opens the sidebar moving the `logo("page-header")` and the `container("main")`.

I wrote this script, it does not work on the first click after the page loads. After the first click, it works fine. I don't understand why it behaves in this way.

Can someone give me a tip to understand what's going on, please? I need to implement this toggle button in pure javascript (no jquery).

```html
var sidebar = false;
function toggle() {
    if (!sidebar) {
        sidebar = true;
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
        document.getElementByClass("page-header").style.marginLeft = "250px";
        return;
    }
    else if (sidebar) {
        sidebar = false;
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
        document.getElementByClass("page-header").style.marginLeft = "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set the default for `sidebar` correctly?  Might be a simple case of `sidebar = true;` on line 1.  Impossible for us to tell without the rest of the HTML markup.  Can you provide the full code?

Comment: I bet you don't bind click event at a proper phase.

Comment: BTW - you can change `else if (sidebar)` to just `else`...

Comment: at least the toggle() method triggers?? on first click

Comment: if I put "else" it doesn't work...
I don't understand why it triggers just on the second click at the very first time. I'm using a Jekyll theme which uses liquid tags.